# How to get the current user id in prestashop version 1.5?

Tags: prestashop

I am new to prestashop. I tried to develop a module. In that module I need the current user id for fetching details from the database. How do I get the current user id in prestashop 1.5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `$this->context->customer->id_customer`. It will be empty if the user is not authenticated

Answer (score 4):

You can get the current user id thanks to the context object :

```
$this->context->customer->id
```

You can find more example of how to use context object here : http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+Context+Object .

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variable `$cookie`. It gives id of customer who is currently logged in.

```
global $cookie;
$user_id = $cookie->id_customer;
```

and then use `$user_id` to fetch details from database.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create a customer object and then call the customer id.

```
$customer = new Customer();
$customer_id = $customer->id;
```